# Modified Content type columns breaks in site template

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, site-template

I have created a site template with a list that uses my content type "ctNews". I have renamed my columns in the content type to different names, and renamed the columns in the site template.

If I now create a new site with my template, the site columns in the list will not change name, they still has the old names.

How can I fix this? I'm on SharePoint 2013 Online

Comment: I just found the same issue. 
I am used to create first the internal name of the columns (for example, "hrDate" for a Date field in the HR department. This comes handy when scripting, and when using search webparts since they display the internal column names). 
This used to work pretty well on premises, but I just moved to online and found the same problem. 
It seems this has not changed since 2014... And we need to be extra careful when applying changes in Site Columns since this will rename all inherited columns back to their original name.